# Alternate definition of condition number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

I am trying to understand if the condition number of a matrix $A$ can be defined as $\left(\frac{\Delta x}{x}\right) / \left(\frac{\Delta b}{b}\right)$ under the following conditions:
$$
Ax = b, \qquad A(x+Δx) = b+Δb
$$
I have seen this definition mentioned, but I am not sure if it is a valid definition for the condition number of a matrix. If this is indeed a valid definition, could you please provide a reference or source that supports this definition?

I am aware of the more common definition of the condition number for a square matrix A, which is defined as:

$Cond(A) = ||A|| ||A^{-1}||$

However, I am specifically interested in understanding if the $\left(\frac{\Delta x}{x}\right) / \left(\frac{\Delta b}{b}\right)$ definition is valid and, if so, under what circumstances it can be used.

Any help or guidance on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, for the obvious reason that $\Delta x/x$ is an ill-defined quantity (and likewise throughout): how does one even define division by a vector?

Comment: Chapter 12 of Trefethen and Bau defines condition numbers in a manner similar to this and uses it to derive the standard definition of the matrix condition number

Comment: @whpowell96 The definition in the book is fine. It has norms around the quantities so it is not dividing vector with vector: $\frac{\|A\delta x\|}{\|\delta x\|} / \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$

Comment: I am aware. I figured norms were implied and answered his question.

Answer (score 1):

You are considering the function $F : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $$F(b) = A^{-1} b. $$ What you seek is known as the componentwise relative condition number of the function $F$. I discuss the abstract definition of normwise and componentwise relative condition numbers of general functions in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3801551/307944) and present formulas that can be used to compute the condition numbers in practice. In your case, the formula is $$\kappa_F^{cr}(b) = \left \| \frac{|A^{-1}||Ax|}{|x|} \right \|_\infty, \quad x = A^{-1}b. $$ The definition and the formula are meaningful provided that every component of $x$ is nonzero. The fraction represents componentwise division between the two vectors $|A^{-1}||Ax|$ and $|x|$. Finally, the vector $|x|$ is given by $(|x|)_i = |x_i|$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What have I done that you perceive as vandalism?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo In my experience, the tag matrices is used mainly for problems that assume exact arithmetic. That is not the case here. Upon inspection, I see that removing the tag matrices was a mistake as the tag description literally includes the phrase "any problem involving matrices". I removed the tag "linear-algebra" as this tag covers the curriculum covered in an introduction to linear algebra and these topics are not important here. I added numerical-methods and numerical-linear-algebra as these tags cover the problem and the solution.

Comment: If there is room for 5 tags, what do you gain by removing them?  I subscribe to tags.  If you remove tags, how can I find questions?